# R Shiny: reload a .Rda file within shiny at a special time of the day

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I wrote a shiny script which loads a Rda-File just at the initial execution. This Rda-file gets updated by an external process. How can I reload the Rda file when it was changed or how can I relaod the .Rda file at a special time, for instance every day at 6 am.

I guess I can use the `reactiveTimer` function and if-clause with `Sys.time()`, but I don't know how.

Thanks a lot for your ideas.

update, thanks to @jdharrison:

I tried the function `reactiveFileReader` and my server.R Skript looks like this:

```
fileData <- reactiveFileReader(10000, session = NULL, filePath = "../data/myData.Rda", load)
 shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
   output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
     fileData()
     myData # this is the name of the R-Object I loaded
   })
 })
```

Unfortunately I always get the error message : mydata not found

How can I use the data which loaded with the `reactiveFileReader` function?

Comment: You can call `reactiveFileReader`. `reactiveFileReader` works by periodically checking the file's last modified time; if it has changed, then the file is re-read and any reactive dependents are invalidated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is quite simple:
just add `envir = .GlobalEnv`

`fileData <- reactiveFileReader(10000, session = NULL, filePath = "../data/myData.Rda", load, envir = .GlobalEnv)`